# Is there a way to send image & pdf document as an attachment in react-quill?

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

In react-quill, uploaded images are expanded in the mail. Is there a way to attach image & pdf document as an attachment in react-quill?

Is there any other text-editor that meets my requirements in react js.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-files you can use this npm package and add the custom text-editor

Comment: @RB19, did you find any solution?